# Radio button returns always false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to save the state of a radio button in mvc.

I have this for the view:

```
  <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.GeneratePDF, new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 ">
            @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.GeneratePDFYes) @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => mailModel.IscheckedPDF, true , new { @checked = "checked", @class = "MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_AttachPdf" })
            @Html.Label(Resources.Entity.Product.GeneratePDFNo)  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => mailModel.IscheckedPDF, false, new {@class = "MAIL_PRODUCT_HANDLERS_AttachPdf" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the check in model:

```
  string IsCheckPDf = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["mailModel.IscheckedPDF"];           
            if (IscheckedPDF == true) 
                IsCheckPDf.Equals("True", StringComparison.Ordinal);                
            else
                IsCheckPDf.Equals("False", StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

but the variable: IscheckedPDF

**Property:**

```
public bool IscheckedPDF { get; set; }
```

returns always **false.**

Thank you

Comment: What is `IscheckedPDF`?

Comment: How does this code compile when you compare `string` to `bool`?

Comment: Can you put the complete action call on the controller?

Comment: Based on your form, your request will not contain `"mailModel.IscheckedPDF"` - just `"IscheckedPDF"`. But since your view uses a model, why aren't you posting back the model instead of using `Request.Form`? And remove the `@checked = "checked"` attribute form your helper! - if the value of `IscheckedPDF` is true, the first button will be selected, otherwise the second one will be

Comment: cast the form value to `bool`

Comment: You never actually set the value of `IscheckedPDF` anywhere...

Comment: Your question title says 'return always true' and the question body says return always false, so adding this true + false is false??

Comment: How are you passing the radio button value to the controller? Post the controller code..is the object bound correctly?

Comment: "and this is the check in model" this check should be performed in the controller!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually set the value of `IscheckedPDF` anywhere in your code. This code doesn't do anything:

```
if (IscheckedPDF == true) 
    IsCheckPDf.Equals("True", StringComparison.Ordinal);                
else
    IsCheckPDf.Equals("False", StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

Instead you can do something like this:

```
IscheckedPDF = IsCheckPDf.Equals("True", StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

Comment: Thank you DavidG. That is the solution :)